# Will sleep/wake buttons work on bluetooth keyboard

Tags: sleep, wake-up, wireless-keyboard

I am thinking about buying a wireless (bluetooth) keyboard to my laptop. I am wondering whether it would be possible to put my laptop to sleep and wake it up via this wireless keyboard. As a matter of fact I pretty confident that sleep function is no problem. But what about waking up?

Comment: "And wake *him* up." You really refer to your computer as *"him"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a 100% answer I know, but exactly this situation works fine on my Mac Mini with a bluetooth keyboard.